# how to make RaisedButton auto fit screen width in flutter

Tags: flutter

Now I am define the RaisedButton width like this in flutter:

```
builder: (context) {
     return ButtonTheme(
            minWidth: 400.0,
            height: 50.0,
            child: RaisedButton()
)}
```

but it could not fit all type of different width of screen, how to make it auto fit? I have tried using 80%, but it seems not work as percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

to get the width of the screen, and then set it to the `minWidth`of the `ButtonTheme` widget.

Also make sure you have wrapped the main widget of the app in `MaterialApp` to be able to access the `MediaQuery` object. Like this:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```